# JSON primitive non valid on Ajax jQuery call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm stuck in this problem i can't solve. I tried many solutions, I also searched adn found many questions also on StackOverflow that aim to solve this problem, but nothing that works for me.
This is my problem:
I have this function

```
$.ajaxWS = function (options) {
    options.url = app.siteUrl + options.url;
    var data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    var defaults = {
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
        converters: {
            "text json": function (jsonString) {
                var res = JSON.parseNet(jsonString);
                if (res && res.hasOwnProperty("d")) res = res.d; //.net 3.5
                return res;
            }
        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            options.success(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(xhr.status != 0)
                options.error(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    return $.ajax(options);
```

};

and when I pass any string in field data, like these

```
 $.ajaxWS({
    url: "urlFunction",
    data: { field1: $('#text1').val(), field2: $('#text2').val() },
    success: function(){
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

it returns always this error

```
{"Message":"JSON primitive not valid: field1.","StackTrace":"   in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromGetRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\r\n   in System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

I found a solution quoting parameters in this manner

```
data: { field1: "'" + $('#text1').val() + "'", field2: "'" + $('#text2').val() + "'" },
```

but this is only a workaround.
I played a lot also with $.ajax options like

```
processData: false,
traditional: true,
```

or passing data not with

```
data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
```

but with only

```
data: options.data,
```

or putting it between quotes, but all of this tries don't work.
I give you another information: this method works with integers and dates. Only strings give problems.
Have you any idea to how solve the problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I've found this to be a bit of a nuisance as well. I persistently use JSON.stringify because writing all those quotes makes your code more error-prone. Is there a reason to not use a function with arguments? If there isn't, just stick with what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is this. passing all data in POST

```
$.ajaxWS = function (options) {
    options.url = app.siteUrl + options.url + (app.SessionID?"?ASPSESSID=" + app.SessionID:"");
    options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);

    var defaults = {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {},
        converters: {
            "text json": function (jsonString) {
                var res = JSON.parseNet(jsonString);
                if (res && res.hasOwnProperty("d")) res = res.d; //.net 3.5
                return res;
            }
        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            options.success(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(xhr.status != 0)
                options.error(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    return $.ajax(options);
```

};

and adding in web.config of my ASP.Net project this line

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS"/>
```

in this manner I can pass quietly params without single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A malformed JSON is probably the cause of your problems.

JSON parsing is very strict. Strings must be ALWAYS enclosed in double quotes. I would recommend passing your generated JSON through http://jsonlint.com/ to spot any error.

Comment: no error, from the validator. try this
{
    "field1": "foo",
    "field2": "foo2",
    "field3": "foo3"
}
but this won't work without single quotes on every parameter

Comment: Instead this works
{
    "field1": "'foo'",
    "field3": "'foo2'",
    "field3": "'foo3'"
}
and is also a valid JSON. I don't understand why the first doesn't work.

Comment: The parameters must be enclosed in DOUBLE quotes (as the code you pasted here), NOT in single quotes as you say you did.

Comment: Yes, understood, but it still doesn't work, with single quotes works.

Comment: Would you set up a working jsfiddle with this? It's king of hard to mentally parse all the code